# Shopping cart on PayPal express checkout

Tags: paypal

I want to add PayPal as a payment method to my website, with express checkout.
I only offer one type of subscription with one price and the same terms for all customers.
Do I still need to integrate a shopping cart or can I just transfer the data to paypal's order summary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are only offering one type of subscription with one price and the same terms for all customers, you would not need to set up a full blown shopping cart.  You can integrate Express Checkout without the use of a shopping cart.